# Laravel Livewire not working after transfering to live server running nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-livewire

I have a problem when I transfer my project to production server, livewire stops working. Server is running nginx.

When I fire wire:click event inside component (click on the button) I get an error in the response:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST. in file /data/*****/****/******/*******/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php on line 118

#0 /data/****/*****/*****/*****/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/AbstractRouteCollection.php(104): Illuminate\Routing\AbstractRouteCollection-&gt;methodNotAllowed()
```

It's a fresh laravel installation with almost empty component, just simple dd(). It's not a full page component, so I do not set type of the route (GET or POST) in the routes/web.php. This component is just called via @livewire() inside blade file. It's working wihout any problem on my local machine with apache on docker and also on another live server with apache.

Do you have any idea what can cause this issue please? Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think u should run `php artisan livewire:publish --assets` to public Livewire